# How can I inspect a phonegap application using Adobe edge inspect?

Tags: cordova, adobe-edge

I can inspect a web page with synchro browsing, but how to inspect a phonegap application on device ? Adobe edge seems to be the tool built by adobe for that purpose, but I can't find any doc on how to use it with phonegap

Comment: Please specify platform.

Comment: Sure, on android 4.2. Got both emulator and device

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have this question too

Answer (score 0):

Edge Inspect CC is mainly for testing websites etc. You can use it to preview your application if you want to edit HTML, CSS and JS in the way that it would work on a webpage - but you won't be able to live debug things that use PhoneGap features as these have to work with native controls etc. which only works in a packaged application.

I use Edge Inspect to test layouts, style etc. but your best bet for debugging is still deploying the APK and using adb logcat.

To preview it as a website, open Edge Inspect CC and Edge Code, point edge code at your www folder then start live preview and the Edge inspect app on your Android device